# Most efficient bit format to represent small unsigned integers

Tags: algorithm

I have to deal with sequences of a lot of small numbers, about a million, and I have to put as many as possible (more is better) in 4KB. Obviously that's just too little space to put all of them. Also, while this is a specific scenario, I'd love an answer as general as possible.

The numbers don't follow any pattern, but here is what a small script has to say about their distribution:

```
407037   times 1
165000   times 2
85389    times 3
52257    times 4
34749    times 5
23567    times 6
15892    times 7
11183    times 8
7636     times 9
5402     times 10
3851     times 11
2664     times 12
2023     times 13
1547     times 14
1113     times 15

... many more lines ...

1    times 62
```

62 is the biggest number I have, so let's set the maximum number we care about at 64. If the method is easily adaptable to accommodate for bigger max numbers, that would be better.

Here is a sample of the numbers:

```
20
1
1
1
13
1
5
1
15
1
3
4
3
2
2
```

A naive way to do this would just be to use 6 bits per number, but I think we can do better.

EDIT: adding a bit of info following discussion in comments.

I also have 2KB of ram and a dozen cycles on a microprocessor to decode each number. I need to store, sequentially, from the first number, as many numbers as I can.

EDIT: see graybeard's comment and my followup too.

Comment: [Huffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) or [Shannon-Fano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding) encoding come to mind. The former being more effective while the latter is somewhat easier to implement.

Comment: Why do you have a 4KB limit? Does this imply other limits, such as CPU and working RAM while accessing them? What access patterns do you need to support? (purely sequential from start to end? random/direct access to any number?)

Comment: Since you can't hold all numbers in 4 KB regardless of the representation, how do you pick the subset to keep?

Comment: One suggestion I have is look into Huffman Coding.  [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)  Without knowing specifics about the data set its hard to say if this is practical or more efficient but it is commonly used in compression algorithms with data that is statistically more common then other.  Its one of the steps in jpeg but can be customized to a specific data set.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - nice point, especially if OP can just pick all the ones.

Comment: I have 2kb of ram available for this and just have a dozen of cycles on a microcontroller fo decode each number. I need to put the numbers from the first until I can, in order. The project is nothing special but I can't say what it is exactly, sorry :(

Comment: I'll add this and a bit more details tomorrow when I can sit at the PC again

Comment: tANS is also a possibility, as fast to decode as Huffman but without rounding probabilities to powers of two so you get better compression. However, like Huffman, it needs a fairly large table to decode it, usually larger than Huffman.

Comment: Do you need to access these numbers by index? _One_ `dozen cycles on a microprocessor to decode each number` is awfully tight. I'd probably go for one nibble for 1-15, and three for all others - less than 28 bits for five numbers. What's the difference if you store 5400 numbers(using 6 bits), instead of 4K? Or about 6K using Huffman (base the statistics on the first 7K, only)? Would it do to silently _drop_ numbers exceeding 16, or have one value for _exceeds 15_?

Comment: nope, only access them sequentially. Storing 6K instead of 4K is about 50% better :) I've been thinking about it and I probably could have one value for exceeds 15. I didn't even consider this. Great idea! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be `Rangecoding`, `Huffman` or `Shannon-Fano` which you can see in any of the digital-communication blogs over the net, so I'm not exactly explaining you these.

I can suggest you a custom method, which is really simple and you can compare it with other methods if you can use this to store more numbers or not.

I see that there are no `0's` in your script. So just decrease each number by 1 (while decoding, add 1 to decoded result). Use either 4 or 7 bits to encode numbers. All numbers up-to `8` can be represented in 3-bits. If the number is `n <= 8`, set the 1st bit as `0` and next 3 bits can represent the number. Else, if the number is `n > 8`, set 1st bit as 1 and represent the number as 6 bits from there.

Though in `Huffman` or `Shannon-Fano`, few of the representations can be as long as over `20 bits`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm leaving the question open for today in case there is some genius answer with some cool custom thingy, otherwise I'm going to accept this and try both huffman and your suggested variable length method.

Comment: Slightly over 23 bits per five numbers, on average. Good, if fast enough.

Comment: Just noticed you get slightly _below_ 23 bits if you use _one_ bit for "1, or something else", with 1+6bits for the latter.

Comment: Yeah..that should improve considering very high frequency for starting numbers.

Comment: `Though in Huffman or Shannon-Fano, few of the representations can be as long as over 20 bits.` - if you are talking about the maximum width of the output code here, then that is dependent on the distribution of symbols. In Huffman, if the greatest population count is greater than the sum of all other pop counts, and the pop count for the second highest is greater than the sum of the rest, and so on, then, for byte-sized input, the width of the two last codes is going to be 255 bits each.

Answer (score 1):

For provide correct answer, need to know - is decoder size also limited, or there is not limit for decodes size?
If no limit for decoder (just limit for data), I suggest you to use [rangecoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_encoding), or [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). Rangecoder has better compression, but extensive arithmetic operation usage.

However, both decoders uses memory for a code, and for statistical tables. So, perhaps, better answer to create something more easy (custom compressor), but with simple and compact code and without any tables. As easy, code-compact, I can propose the run-1 algorithm. This algorithm is not very efficient for your data (rangecoder or Huffman better), but has trivial compact decoder without any tables.

Idea - sequence can contain zero or more bit_1, and use bit_0 as symbol separator. For example, if we would like encode with run-1 the sequence:

```
1, 1, 2, 1, 5
```

There will be bit sequence:

```
0-0-10-0-11110
```

There, you needed just count number of sequenced bit_1, add 1, and return value as decoded number.

Comment: `is decoder size also limited` - well, there's `a dozen cycles on a microprocessor to decode each number`. If _every_ instruction was a conditional branch, you ominously get 4K instructions …

Answer (score 1):

Maybe slightly better than straight Huffman can be attempted by combining with run-length coding.

If you count the successive identical elements, you can rewrite your sequence as a pairs of (value, count). Every such pair appears with some probability and you can use Huffman coding on these. (I don't mean to code the values and the counts separately, but the pairs as a whole).

Your sample yields

```
(20, 1), (1, 3), (13 1), (1, 1), (5, 1), (1, 1), (15, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (3, 1), (5, 2)
```

The singletons will be (practically) coded as before, and there are more opportunities for compression of longer runs.

You can limit the maximum count(s) that are supported; if the actual count exceeds the limit, it is no big deal to insert several pairs.

The very first step is to compute an histogram of the count values to see if there are enough repetitions for this approach to be worth.

---

Alternatively, you can try Huffman coding on the deltas (signed differences between successive values). If there are many repetitions, the frequency of 0 will be much higher, increasing the entropy. Obviously, run-length coding of the deltas is also possible.

Comment: I will definitely try this and run a search for the best maximum count. Thanks.

Comment: @mfran: the way the initial sequence is generated might hint you other ways to group the values into micro-patterns, such as pairs of successive values, to make very high frequencies appear.

Answer (score 1):

I took the distribution you listed, and tried an exponential fit. The result was decently good:

[image]

More importantly, the fit was reasonably close to `p(x) ~= 2^-x`. This suggests a very simple coding, known as "unary coding": to encode the number `k`, output `k-1` zeroes, followed by a 1. If your numbers exactly fit the `p(x) ~= 2^-x` distribution, that would give you an expected code length of 2 bits. Since your numbers appear to be heavier-tailed than that (otherwise it would be vanishingly unlikely to see a 62 in only a million numbers), you won't quite achieve that. Still, given the simplicity of the coding and the ease of decoding (twelve cycles should be sufficient), you should consider trying it out.

You might also look into other universal codes, such as Elias Delta. Golomb coding would be optimal, but decoding it is an involved process.

Comment: See the 2nd part of [maxihatop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34583405/3789665)'s answer and argue how to implement it not exceeding `a dozen cycles on a microprocessor to decode each number`.